# Updating Tabs on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

When I select a city from my 3rd tab, I want to it to show up in the “Map” tab. For example, when I first select “Austin” as the city, it shows up on the map (as shown in the picture bellow). But when I go back to the “City” tab again and choose a different city, it doesn’t get updated in the “Map” tab. Can you please tell me if there is a way I can refresh the “MapsActicity” each time I click on the “Map” tab.

```
public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {`

    private TabHost mtabHost;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      

        Resources res = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  
        Intent intent;  
        mtabHost = getTabHost();
        mtabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, BarActivity.class);        
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Name").setIndicator("Name",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_bar)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MapsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Map").setIndicator("Map",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_map)).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CityActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("city").setIndicator("City", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_city)).setContent(intent); 
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }

    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {        
        int a = mtabHost.getCurrentTab();
        String b = Integer.toString(a); 
        if(b.equals("1"))
        {           
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Map Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }               
    } 
}
```

[image]

Update:

```
     `public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity 
     {  
MapView mapView;  
MapController mc;
GeoPoint p;`

class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
    boolean shadow, long when) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow); 
        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);
         Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.pushpin);            
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);         
        return true;
    }
 }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main4);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);


    String []coordinates = new String[4];
    coordinates[0] = "33.477863"; coordinates[1] = "-101.855166"; //Just in-case user didn't choose a city 

    if(CityActivity.value.equals("Austin")) { //This 'value' is recived from CityActivity. Depending on what city user chooses.
        coordinates[0] = "30.260053"; coordinates[1] = "-97.738593"; }
    else if(CityActivity.value.equals("Dallas")) {
        coordinates[0] = "33.554519"; coordinates[1] = "-101.855621"; }
    else if(CityActivity.value.equals("Slaton")) {
        coordinates[0] = "33.577863"; coordinates[1] = "-101.855166"; }


    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

    p = new GeoPoint(
        (int) (lat * 1E6), 
        (int) (lng * 1E6));

    mc = mapView.getController();
    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(16); 
    mapView.invalidate();

    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);     
    mapView.invalidate();
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}  }
```

Comment: You have to use onResume() method in city tab to maintain last updated city.

Comment: The main reason is that, when you click first on the map, a new map activity is being loaded. On second click on the map tab, the activity has already been loaded and onCreate method is not called. You can use onStart/onResume method to refresh/load your data on the map activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply. can you please edit the above code and show me how to use OnResume(). I am new to this and still learning.

Comment: Post the MapActivity's code.The changes have to be there.

Comment: I have posted the MapActivity code at the end of the original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String []coordinates = new String[4];
coordinates[0] = "33.477863"; coordinates[1] = "-101.855166"; //Just in-case user didn't choose a city 

if(CityActivity.value.equals("Austin")) { //This 'value' is recived from CityActivity. Depending on what city user chooses.
    coordinates[0] = "30.260053"; coordinates[1] = "-97.738593"; }
else if(CityActivity.value.equals("Dallas")) {
    coordinates[0] = "33.554519"; coordinates[1] = "-101.855621"; }
else if(CityActivity.value.equals("Slaton")) {
    coordinates[0] = "33.577863"; coordinates[1] = "-101.855166"; }


double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

p = new GeoPoint(
    (int) (lat * 1E6), 
    (int) (lng * 1E6));


mc = mapView.getController();
mc.animateTo(p);
mc.setZoom(16); 
mapView.invalidate();

MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
listOfOverlays.clear();
listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);     
mapView.invalidate();
```

Try to move this peace of code in OnResume() Method

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the information. Now it works well. you were a big help.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please tell me if there is a way I can refresh the “MapsActicity” each time I click on the “Map” tab.

First move your focus to the new city

```
  mapController.animateTo(new GeoPoint(   (int) (lat * 1E6), 
        (int) (lng * 1E6))
```

or
`mapView.invalidate()` /  `mapView.postInvalidate()` to refresh your maps.

Comment: Thanks you for the detailed answer. I have tried that, but no luck. can you please look in to my updated question above and give me an example.